# Попадать в такт: чего, чему или с чем? Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

*Солдаты, **в такт песни** размахивая руками, шли просторным шагом, невольно попадая в ногу.* [чего? Р. п.]
[**Л. Толстой. Война и мир**](http://rubook.org/book.php?book=175105&page=51)

*Вместе с плотной толпой других пассажиров Робин покачивалась **в такт движению** поезда метро...* [чему? Д. п.]
[**Р. Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки**](http://knizhnik.org/robert-gelbrejt/zov-kukushki/12)

*Каблуки ее белых туфель выбивали четкую дробь, попадали **в такт с биением** сердца.*
[с чем? Т. п.]
[**К. Щукинская. Лабиринты**](http://www.rulit.me/books/labirinty-read-459665-13.html)

Хотелось бы понять: возможны ли все три варианта согласования или какой-то из них предпочтительнее? Как правильно говорить: в такт *чего*, в такт *чему* или в такт *с чем*?

Answer (score 2):

Возможны все три падежа:

1) Такт музыки (Р.п.), в такт музыки. Это **определение**, музыкальный такт.

2) В такт музыке (Д.п.). Это **соответствие** такта музыки и движения, преднамеренное или случайное.

3) В так с музыкой (Т.п.). Это  **подбор** такта движения, музыка (или другое колебание) как ориентир. Обычно намеренный, иногда случайный.

Примеры

Я долго смотрел на эту запись, мысли мои, как могу судить я сейчас, несколько путались; надпись дрожала **в такт дрожания пальцев**. [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

Чайная ложечка в стакане мерно позвякивала **в такт колесам**, как во времена Чука и Гека. [Сергей Каледин. Аллея Руж // «Огонек», 2013].  Трамвай прокатывается по кольцу и уходит под гору, **в такт ему** качаются на столе фотографии. [Валерия Иванова. Льдинки // «Сибирские огни», 2012]

Страдаете от укачивания? Не дышите **в такт с качкой**!  Или, например, колонна солдат, шагающая по мосту, может раскачать его так, что он рухнет ― если они будут шагать **в такт с его собственными колебаниями**.Торгуйте на колебаниях вверх или вниз **в такт с рынком**. [Как управлять торговлей // Forex Magazine, 2004]

Comment: Думаю, что "в такт дрожани**я**" - ошибка: есть "такт музыки" но не существует "такта дрожания" как буквализма.

Comment: Ну это метафора. Человек ощущает внутреннюю дрожь, ему кажется, что дрожание пальцев и  текста (при его зрительном восприятии)  соответствуют друг другу.

Comment: Метафоричны выражения "в такт (чему-то)" и "в такт (с чем-то)". Но выражение "[попадая] в такт музык**и**", на мой взгляд, буквально и держится на понятии музыкального такта (или такта какого-л. муз. произведения). В сравнении со случаем "дрожания", более очевиден был бы диссонанс в выражении "в такт рынка".

Comment: @Jasmin  Я споткнулась, собственно, на втором предложении: мне показалось, что правильно будет " покачивалась в такт движения поезда" (чего? Р. п.). А в известной песне "Мчится поезд, поезд мчится
И навязчиво маняще,
В такт колёс в висках стучится..." - как правильно: стучится в такт колёс, или в такт колёсам, или в такт с колёсами?

Comment: В такт колес и в такт колесам - обе формы возможны,  первая подходит под размер стиха. В принципе между всеми формами нет противостояния, но есть некоторое различие в смысловых оттенках.

Answer (score 1):

Второй и третий варианты универсальны и означают "*в соответствии с ритмом чего-то*" или "*сообразно ритму чего-то*" (два варианта управления). Этот самый ритм или такт условен, как и мера соответствия ему. В случае же "**музыки**" (или песни, как здесь) возможны не только эти два варианта, но и (как показывают множественные книжные примеры) буквальная трактовка "такта" музыкального произведения с указанием на точное следование ему (как в первом примере - из Толстого - военная музыка как раз предполагает движение строя строго *в такт "музык**и***", подчинение её ритму). Менее обязывающее "*в такт музык**е***" подходит не только для танцевальных движений, но и напр. для постукивания пальцем по столу или причмокивания.