# Сокращаться в ритм или в ритме?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Подскажите, будьте добры, как правильно?

*Его мышцы сокращались в ритм(е) со стуком молота.*

Answer (score 1):

Не берусь найти все возможные варианты, но я бы сказал немного по-другому:

> *Его мышцы сокращались **в ритм стуку** молота.*

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, правильный выбор зависит от *присутствия* или отсутствия предмета, на ритм звучания (движения) которого ссылаются. **В ритм** или в такт **тому**, что *присутствует*, может производиться другое действие - это о *синхронизации* движения, в технических терминах "по фазе". Если же говорят о сходстве по ритму с движением чего-то *воображаемого*, то **в ритме** этого (снежинки кружились *в ритме вальса*), - в ритме, свойственном движению или звучанию того, с чем сопоставляют. Технически это сопоставление по "частоте" или темпу.

В нашем случае по смыслу трудно отнести "стук молота" к общепринятому или понятному всем эталону ритма - стало быть, по контексту этот звук *присутствует*. Соответственно, правилен в свете приведённых рассуждений вариант "**в ритм стуку**" (с точки зрения наблюдателя, своими движениями мышцы "вторят" этому стуку в ритм), или (если не трогать предлог) можно сказать "*вместе со стуком* молота". Книжный пример:

> *– Я должен исполнить свой долг! - **в ритм стуку** сердца и хрусту снега*
>   *под ногами твердил он.* (М. Серегин, Пастырь из спецназа, 2019)

Comment: Интересные рассуждения, Александр! Полностью согласен со всем, сам не смог дойти до этого. И приятно, что ответ подтверждает, что меня не обманула интуиция. ;) Не понял только, зачем *частоту* закавычили.

Comment: Закавычил по той же причине, что и фазу, с которой слово перекликается в тексте как технический термин, измеряемый в герцах :)

Answer (score 0):

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
РИТМ -а; м. [греч. rhythmos]
1. Равномерное чередование каких-л. элементов (звуковых, двигательных и т. п.). ***Ритм дыхания. Ритм сердца.*** / О согласованности элементов в художественном произведении как средстве создания его композиции. *Ритм цветов и красок в коллаже. Ритм букета.*

Ритм (чего?) танца, ритм движений, ритм стиха, **ритм стука молота** (Р. п.).

[Универсальный словарь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=fdEdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85&source=bl&ots=n3pmqOv_c7&sig=ACfU3U1Zp7sFUX3YvvSY8Qb33-0K55r6hw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9z_ebtJnjAhUolIsKHbrLA78Q6AEwBXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%85&f=false):
танец
2. *Ряд движений определённой формы и темпа, исполняемых **в такт** музыке, а также музыкальное произведение **в ритме** и стиле **таких движений.***

Думаю, что правильно должно быть так.
**Его мышцы сокращались в ритме стука молота.**

Дополнение

Достаточно к "ритму" добавить определение, чтобы стало понятно, что необходим именно родительный падеж (например, "сокращались в быстром ритме" — нельзя сказать "сокращались в быстрый ритм").
Сравните: *Если между клетками в процессе их роста устанавливаются функциональные взаимосвязи, то они начинают **сокращаться в одном ритме** (**в ритме той клетки**, которая сокращается наиболее часто).*

Я думаю, что путаница в падежах происходит из-за подмены понятий — *сокращаться **в ритме*** (чего?), но *сокращаться **в такт*** (чего? чему? с чем?).
(См.: [Попадать в такт: чего, чему или с чем? Как правильно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435872/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/435875#435875))

Comment: В Нацкорпусе много таких примеров: глагол (колебались, покачивались, кружились) + в ритм чему-то. Я чуть не собрался удалить свой ответ, но нашёл, слава Богу, подтверждение своему варианту. То есть можно двигаться или что-то ещё делать не только в такт чему-то, но и в ритм.

Comment: Не знаю-не знаю, Артём... _Покой, которого мне так не хватало, когда я **жил в бешеном ритме большого города_** (А. Арсеньев). Вы ведь не скажете "жил в бешеный ритм большому городу". Или скажете?

Comment: С "жил" по-другому, да. А с движениями всякими как раз часто дательный падеж бывает.

Comment: Кстати, дефисное написание двойного "не знаю" нельзя оправдать, потому что дефис может разделять только два слова, между которыми стоит, а не словосочетания, некоторые слова которых отделены пробелом.

Comment: *с движениями всякими* — да, и со звуками, конечно, тоже.